# PECL Adding gearman to php extension

Tags: php, yii-extensions, php-extension, pecl, gearman

Hi i'm really having a hard time here, 
I'm trying to install [gearman](http://gearman.org/) job/task queue. I'm using windows, wappstack to be exact, then followed exactly the instructions  [here](http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/), and so far so good. I think **I've installed the gearman server.**

But I can't seem to find how to actually **install PECL extension for gearman.** I mean I can't find any **.dlls** to add to the PHP ext folder. and the PECL Package [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) just makes me all the more clueless. I can't invoke Gearman classes, and when I use **phpinfo();** , gearman extension is just not present. I'm absolutely clueless on this.

How do I add and properly set up gearman extension to my PHP? Please and Thank you!

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes. unfortunately no luck, i should see the gearman in the phpinfo(); right?

Comment: @scheisse_minelli this is really weird because whenever i intall php extensions like memcached, I usually donwload some dll stuff, and add it to ext folder. but this ones really weird, can you share your experience on how you've installed this?

Answer (score 0):

To you install a extensions of PECL you need use the cmd.

- Open the cmd.
- Go to directory where is the PHP program.
- Find for "pecl.exe"
- Install gearman extension.

Like:

> $ cd C:/BitNami/wappstack-[version]/php/
>   $ pecl install gearman

- Now, looking for the "php_gearman.dll" in the extension directory.
- And add extension to php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Comment: i got an error... says "C:\bitnami\wappstackphp\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match, ERROR : The DSP gearman.dsp does not exist.

Comment: try: 
 `$ pecl config-set php_suffix .exe`
 and `$ pecl config-set php_bin C:\bitnami\wappstackphp\php.exe` 

And try repeat the process. 

I'm reading [bug.php#17016](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17016)

Comment: both commands return "config-set succeded" but i still have the same error

Comment: still we are also getting same error message that is ERROR : The DSP gearman.dsp does not exist.